# Ng select model selection gets overriden by html5 selected

Tags: angularjs, html

Ok so I have a select

```
        <select id="minutes-to-dropdown" 
            required="" 
            ng-model="AddEventPopupStore.ToMinutes" 
            name="minutes-to-dropdown" 
            ng-change="AddEventPopupStore.UpdateTimeFromPopup()" 
            ng-options="num as num for num in [0,15,30,45]" 
            class="popup-subdropdown">
          <option disabled="" value="">min</option>
        </select>
```

and it's used for a popup which is toggled via `ng-show` (not sure how this affects destructing/recreating scope)

What happens is that the `selected` property does not update properly when the selection changes from both clicks and model. After a few updates I get

```
        <select id="minutes-to-dropdown" 
            required="" 
            ng-model="AddEventPopupStore.ToMinutes" 
            name="minutes-to-dropdown" 
            ng-change="AddEventPopupStore.UpdateTimeFromPopup()" 
            ng-options="num as num for num in [0,15,30,45]" 
            class="popup-subdropdown">
          <option disabled="" value="" selected="selected">min</option>
          <option label="0" value="number:0" selected="selected">0</option>
          <option label="15" value="number:15" selected="selected">15</option>
          <option label="30" value="number:30" selected="selected">30</option>
          <option label="45" value="number:45" selected="selected">45</option>
        </select>
```

and while the model changes when I pick another value, if I close the popup and reopen it the the model and the selection don't match because the last `selected` value is shown instead of the actual `selected` from model.

How do I force updating of the selection to the actual selection from model? I suppose I might have to force removing of all the `selected`s and reapply it to the new one.

Comment: Why do you have a construct like that? with `ngOptions` you shouldn't use `option` elements, secondly when browser renders `options` it would selected value to the last element that has `selected="selected"` as only one element is supposed to have select (unless you use multiselect)

Comment: Yeah but the  thing is that angular doesn't remove old selecteds when selecting a new one  via model

Comment: what do you mean by angular doesn't remove? Give me example

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/VrvP86t.gifv

Comment: I see that the select has correct model when you open popup, you shouldn't be concerned with the HTML generated with `ngOptions`

Comment: Yeah but when I reopen the popup the values displayed to the user are not the same as in the model because the form shows the last selected value

Comment: In that case it's most-likely the model issue or popup scope problem it's hard to debug it with as little code